# erasing the selected portion of bitmap in canvas

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to erase the selected portion of the bitamp which is drawing over the canvas.. How to do it??? please help me out...Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can clip the canvas to allow draw only in the "clipped zone".

[Canvas | clipRect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipRect%28android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Region.Op%29)

If you clip the canvas with the rect, you can draw everything you want in the canvas but the zone clipped only will be drawed in the canvas.

Comment: hey i have copied the selected portion into another bitmap... My problem is i have select the portion from the bitmap and copting that portion in the same bitmapp.. so i am not able to delete the selected portion..

Comment: You can _delete_ a portion. You can drawing **above** it or create a new bitmap with the desired portion.

Comment: I mean "You **can't** delete a portion" :)